# Region bounded by the parabola $\, y=x^2\;$ and the line $\, y=16\;$ What is the volume of the solid generated when R is rotated about $y = 17$?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Let R be the region bounded by the parabola $ \, y=x^2\;$ and the line $\, y=16\;. $

What is the volume of the solid generated when R is rotated about the line $\, y=17 \; ? 
$

So there's outer radius, and inner radius. What's my outer radius? $17-16 = 1$?

And inner radius is just $x^2 - 16$?

So the formula for integration is is  $\pi \cdot 1^2 + \pi \cdot (x^2 - 16)^2$

Right? And then the intervals are between $- \sqrt{17}$ and $\sqrt{17}$

But [the answer I get](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%20pi%2B%20pi%20*%20%28x%5E2-16%29%5E2%20from%20-sqrt%2817%29%20to%20sqrt%2817%29): $\frac{4004 \sqrt(17) \pi}{15}$ seems to be wrong...

p.s. Okay, it has a hole in it, outer radius (actual thing I'm finding) - inner radius (the hole).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outer radius $R$ should be the distance from the curve furthest from the axis of rotation and the axis. In your case, $R=17-x^2.$  Inner radius, $r$ is the distance between the curve closest to the axis of rotation and the axis. In your case, $r=17-16=1.$  The integral for your volume then is
$$\pi\int_{-4}^4(R^2-r^2)dx.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: so if the problem instead said: "R is revolved around y = 16" Would I then use the formula for Volume: $x^2 - 16$ or $16 - x^2$?

Comment: Because you are squaring the radius, the order of subtraction doesn't matter - meaning you'll produce the right answer either way. But technically it should be $16-x^2$ to keep values positive. I find this good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Notice:

$$\text{Outer radius }=r_o=17-x^2\qquad\text{and}\qquad\text{Inner radius }=r_i=17-16=1$$

Then, since $y=x^2$ meets the line $y=16$ at $(-4,16)$ and $(4,16)$, we have
\begin{align*}
V&=\int_{-4}^{4}\pi (r_o^2-r_i^2)\,\mathrm d x\\
 &=\pi\int_{-4}^{4} \left[(17-x^2)^2-1^2\right]\,\mathrm d x\\
\end{align*}

Comment: but when I solve the same problem, except R is revolved around y = 16, I use $\pi \cdot (x^2 - 16)^2 $ and get the right answer... so I don't understand why it's so different here...

Comment: "the (inner) radius r is given by the distance from the bottom boundary of the region to the axis of rotation" Shouldn't it be for my case be $x^2 - 16$?

Comment: Your solid has a hole in it, so you have to integrate 'washer' cross sections rather than discs.

Comment: @John Molokach  ah... gotcha, now it makes sense!